# AppleScript to open a URL from Calendar using Google Chrome depending on the first part of it

Tags: applescript

I want to make an AppleScript to, if the first part of the link is ____ it will open it in Chrome.

```
open http://stackoverflow.com -a "Google Chrome"
```

I got that, but how would I do it depending on the first part of the link.

For example, if the first part of it is `https://meet.google.com/xxx-xxxx-xxx` to open in Google Chrome.

The `xxxxx` changes every time.

Alternative solutions welcomed too.

Comment: yes, chrome isn't my default browser but if the links start with that to open them in chrome

Comment: How do you plan on passing the URL that you would want to open  In Google Chrome, to the AppleScript?

Comment: @wch1zpink not really sure, split it into two parts and then join them together?

Comment: Is this the scenario you would like? You are browsing in Safari and you come across the link that starts with `https://meet.google.com/` and when you click that link while in Safari, you want it to open in Google Chrome instead?

Comment: @wch1zpink kind of. the link will be in the calender application and i click it and if it begins with the meet.google.com it opens in chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an *alternative solution*, tested under **macOS High Sierra 10.13.6** and it worked:

- **Automator** > **New** > **Service**

  - With settings: **Service receives selected *text* in *Calendar***
- Add a **Run Shell Script** *action*, with settings:

  - **Shell:** */bin/bash*
  - **Pass input:** *as arguments*
  - Replace the *default code* with: `open "$1" -a "Google Chrome"`
- Save it as: **Open URL in Google Chrome**

Then in **Calendar**, right click on the **URL** and select **Open URL in Google Chrome** from the **Services** context menu.

*It's not a single click scenario, but gets the job done.*

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the value for xxx-xxxx-xxx, It's difficult to give an exact answer. I think if you look at the variables I set, This code should give you a good starting point to work with

```
set baseURL to "https://meet.google.com/"
set openURL to "https://meet.google.com/xxx-xxxx-xxx"

if openURL contains baseURL then do shell script "open " & openURL & " -a 'Google Chrome'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Automator answer above, but get this error:

"The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “The file /Users/me/⁨https:/meet.google.com/hhhh-hhhh-hhh⁩ does not exist.”

It seems to add my local file directory to the URL?

(Using Automator V2.10)